# Iterate over lists stored in dict values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I can't find anything that solves my problem.

I have a function testdata() that returns data slices as a dictionary. The keys are numbered as text (with a leading zero) for reference.

The function returns the below dict...

```
mydict = {}
some stuff here   
pprint(mydict)
{'01': [u'test1',
        u'test2',
        u'test3'],
 '02': [u'test4',
        u'test5',
        u'test6'],
 '03': [u'test7',
        u'test8',
        u'test9']
 }
```

I now want to send the slices's (01, 02, 03) key values, one by one to another function as a comma separated list/string.

So first iteration would be to access '01' and create the list 'test1,test2,test3' then send it as an argument to my other function analysis(arg).

Here's what I have...

```
getdata = testdata() # 
for x in getdata:
    incr = 0
    analysis(x['01': incr])
    incr += 1
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:root:Unexpected error:(<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>, TypeError('slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method',), <traceback object at 0x10351af80>)
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation error if right ? Also try this syntax `analysis(x['01'][incr])`

Comment: you are setting `incr = 0` so `incr` is an int, but then you do `incr(0)` which is calling it like a function. You can't call an int.

Comment: @ChadS. Sorry I have updated. That was a typo.

Comment: @itsneo not sure what indent you mean

Comment: @ChadS. analysis(x['01'][incr]) has the same result 'ERROR:root:Unexpected error:(<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>, TypeError('slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method',), <traceback object at 0x10351af80>)'

Comment: Ok then, if `testdata()` returns the dict you showed above, then when you iterate `x in getdata` you are iterating over the keys in the dict. (e.g. '01', '02', etc). To get the list at that key you would need to use `getdata[x]` which would give you the whole list. To iterate the items in that list you could use a loop inside this loop like `for item in getdata[x]`

Comment: I think you need to read more tutorials and play around with simpler data structures until you get a handle on how dicts work.

Comment: @ChadS. Thanks for the tip of do more tutorials. I don't want to iterate over the lists stored as values. Only the keys, returning the comma separated lists as a string. One by one to analysis(arg)

Comment: I mentioned about indentation error, since you have added a tab after this line `getdata = testdata()` Which isn't right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
keys = list(getdata) # Create a `list` containing the keys ('01', '02', ...)
sort(keys) # the order of elements from `list` is _unspecificed_, so we enforce an order here
for x in keys:
    css = ",".join(getdata[x]) # Now you have css = "test1,test2,test3"
    analysis(css) # dispatch and done
```

Or, even more succinctly (but with the same internal steps):

```
for x in sorted(getdata):
    analysis(",".join(getdata[x]))
```

As for your error, it's telling you that you can't use a string in slice notation.  Slice notation is reserved for `[lo:hi:step]`, and doesn't even work with `dict` anyway.  The easiest way to "slice" a `dict` is through a dict comprehension.

Comment: I used the succinct one. I'll suggest edits to match my function names for anyone that needs it in the future. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
    In [2]: dic
    Out[2]: 
    {'01': [u'test1', u'test2', u'test3'],
     '02': [u'test4', u'test5', u'test6'],
     '03': [u'test7', u'test8', u'test9']}

    In [6]: for k,v in dic.iteritems():
   ...:     print k,v
   ...:     
02 [u'test4', u'test5', u'test6']
03 [u'test7', u'test8', u'test9']
01 [u'test1', u'test2', u'test3']
```

So i guess you could just do a ..

```
analysis(k,v)
```

Answer (score 0):

`analysis(x['01': incr])` when doing `['01': incr]` you're using the list slice operator `:`, and is supposed to be used with integer indices. `incr` is an `int`, but `'01'` is a string.

If you only want to iterate of the dict values (the corresponding lists), its enough to do:

```
for key, the_list in mydict.iteritems():
    analysis(the_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example step by step of how this could be done..

```
gendata = {
 '01': [u'test1',u'test2',u'test3'],
 '02': [u'test4',u'test5',u'test6'],
 '03': [u'test7',u'test8',u'test9']
 }

#iterate over the keys sorted alphabetically 
#   (e.g. key=='01', then key=='02', etc)

for key in sorted(gendata):  
    value_list = gendata[key]  # e.g. value_list=['test1', 'test2, 'test3']
    joined_string = ','.join(value_list) # joins the value_list's items with commas
    analysis(joined_string) #calls the function with 'test1,test2,test3'
```